# Recyclerview load more lost item click when scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with Recyclerview item click. I fetch data to `list()` method and add via `addItem()` method in recyclerview custom adapter when scroll down in `addOnScrollListener`. I get item position  with click interface on Fragment. First fetch data work perfectly but when fetch loadmore, can't retrive item positon to new data with `onButtonLClick()` method.

```java
// in onBindViewHolder;

holder.lnl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    rcylviewItemNotify.onButtonLClick(position);
                }catch (Throwable e){
                    //interface can be null
                }
            }
});

// addItem() method in adapter;

public void addItem(List<Image> img) {
        for (Image im : img) {
            arrayList.add(im);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

// interface code;

public interface RcylviewItemNotify {
    void onButtonLClick(int position);
}

// in Fragment code;

   public void list() {
        GetServices service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetServices.class);
        Call<Images> call = service.getImages();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Images>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Images> call, Response<Images> response) {
                Images body = response.body();
                records = body.getImages();
                adapter.addItem(records);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Images> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network hatası onFailure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                reflesh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

 @Override
    public void onButtonLClick(int position) {
        final String clickId = String.valueOf(records.get(position).getID());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ID: " + clickId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

// recycler settings;

    public void loadView() {
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        Collections.reverse(records);
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,(ArrayList<Image>) records, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        reflesh.setRefreshing(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your issue but you should be using the `ViewHolder` to get the position. Inside of your `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    int itemPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();

    // Then do whatever you need to with the position 
}
```

Comment: I already bring the position with RcylviewItemNotify interface method.My problem is when add more item in recyclerview cant get it new item information

Comment: @egencoglu It looks like you're using the position directly in your `onClick` which can be unreliable and could cause errors or inconsistencies. When you're using the position from inside another function that you're calling within your `onBindViewHolder` function, you should get the position from the holder. The holder's position will be much more reliable.

Comment: I solved when add onClick in onBindViewHolder: and add data to new arraylist in my list() method.Thank you